# Custom Dictionary Implementation: Can I Create My Custom affix file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, dictionary, hunspell

I am using this [Hunsplell iOS Implementation](https://github.com/aaronSig/Hunspell-iOS).

And I want to create my custom dictionary and affix file with my choice of words.

I know how to create .dic files but I have no idea how to generate the affix file with .aff extension for that respective .dic file. Is there any tool or technique which I am not getting by googling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution which worked for me is in two parts:

1. Writing .aff file by your own is a pretty lengthy and difficult task. So if you want to create your own custom dictionary(provided it is not very complex and deep in lexical terms) just create an empty file in notepad and save it with .aff extension, it will work fine.
2. I came through this problem because I wanted to merge two different Hunspell Dictionaries with their .aff and .dic files. And I found a brilliant FREE [Hunspell Merge](https://code.google.com/p/hunspell-merge/downloads/list) tool which can merge Hunspell Dictionaries (both .aff and .dic files) generating combined .aff and .dic files.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this meets your needs, but in my case as the custom dictionary I was building was in English I just used the standard en_US.aff and renamed it to match my custom dictionary name.

I used this in an app I built and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Best explanation I’ve seen around is at Chromium: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/editing-the-spell-checking-dictionaries

Looking at other popular dictionaries from OpenOffice will give you a sense of some more sophisticated ways to write .aff rules:
http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary
Most dictionaries there are under the GNU GPL.

AFAIK, .aff files are written, not necessarily generated so I’m not aware of any tools. The real difficulty is in the sheer volume of words in a given language, possible transformations, and morphological complexity of a language at hand.